# Find the area of the largest square that contains exactly $n$ lattice points

Tags: geometry, area

A point $(x,y)$ in the plane is called a lattice point if both $x$ and $y$ are integers. Find the area of the largest square that contains exactly $n$ lattice points in its interior.

This question is inspired by 1998 AHSME Problem 29, where $n=3$. In that case, it suffices to consider squares containing $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$. Note that an optimal square must have parallel sides containing lattice points, and the distance between parallel lines through $(0,-1)$ and $(1,1)$ is $\leq \sqrt{5}$, so the largest possible area for the square is $5$. In fact, The following four lines intersect to form a square containing exactly $3$ lattice points with area $5$:

$$2x-y=-2, \quad 2x-y=3, \quad x+2y=-2, \quad x+2y=3.$$

[$\hspace{3cm}$[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9kFC.png)

[Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) might be useful if one can translate the lattice so that all the vertices of square fall on points of the new lattice.

Comment: Just to be clear, the vertices of the square need not lie on lattice points right?

Comment: It is far from obvious that there is a square for every $n$.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Griboullis Great point.

Comment: There is indeed a square for every $n$ (though this fact does require a proof in its own right), but I don't think we can find the area of the _largest_ such square in a closed form. It is a pretty complicated thing, maybe as much so as **not** to be a monotonic function of $n$.

Comment: It is clear that you assume tritely packed n point - 3 on a line can not be packed in a square without having additional lattice points in the square.